# I've programmatically created an SVG. How do I 'crop' it?

Tags: svg, crop, laser-cutting

I used Processing to generate this SVG.

[image: Original SVG drawing]

As you can see, it's a series of triangles with trapezoids that gradually get smaller. It came out great, except I want to 'crop' the image to look like this.

[image]

Ultimately I want to laser cut this drawing. A laser cutter needs an SVG in order to work, so I can't rasterize and crop. How can I join the border shapes to form a complete SVG?

Sorry if this isn't clear, I'm new to graphic design.

Comment: Laser cutting isnt exactly graphic design.

Comment: If there's a better stack exchange I'd be happy to post there. I needed help with graphic design tools so I figured this was an appropriate place.

Comment: Graphic design is not about tools its about the purpose you solve by graphical means. SVG is no more a graphics design tool than an excel file is a accounting agency. But yes you have the answer. Though why not use your program to cut the design?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction you're making. To answer your question, I was having issues programmatically solving the problem so I was turning to SVG editors.

Comment: If that's the case then you have not asked that question, perhaps you should start with what application you were planning to use. [Intersecting 2 lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) shouldn't be so hard. But that said what your doing makes little sense for the laser cutter. PS: SVG is a format among many others. Also usually you do not call them SVG editors but rather vector graphics editors. Calling them SVG editors would be like calling spreadsheets comma separated value editors. But see that's not what they really do.

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is a perfectly on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, "crop" means to block something with something else. So is a bitmap term... pixels or edges or something else cover up something else, hence it's cropped.

The term you want is "trim" or "cut", and the tools you'll need are going to perform a slice like action to your vector (SVG) imagery.

1. Find a vector editor you like. These are CorelDraw, Illustrator, etc...
2. Learn how to draw a box and place it over the parts you want to "cut" away.
3. Check out the boolean tools, they permit you to do "slicing" or "cutting" that removes what you don't want by using the box as a "cutter".

I'm using all the wrong words, so that the process can become clear, each program has its own specific terms for these actions and processes... but the principles are the same: One thing slices and then removes something else based upon the space it's taking up. Hence the programming sounding "boolean" word is often used for this stuff.

Alternative solution:

Use a vector editor to break apart your SVG, and then you can individually select each of the triangles you want to delete, and delete them. But it looks like you'll still need to do some slicing to get the straight edge results at the bottom of your image.